# View multiple PDF side by side

Tags: osx, pdf, pdf-viewer, documentation-viewer

I have a feeling that I just had a milion dollar idea, a PDF viewer which allows viewing multiple PDF files at the same time, side by side. Like this:

[image]

Or that thing already exist? I mean one app (just one instance), so that I can select multiple PDFs from the file manager, then right click and I should see something like the one shown above.

The files should scroll independently.

Comment: Synchronizing both with each other is a big issue in that case (one or more scrollbars (?). It is currently already possible by just starting multiple readers and align them.

Comment: Question edited to address the sync issue. I was thinking about one scroll per file. Start multiple readers and align them will take much more time.

Comment: Independent scrolling would mean that the viewer has to have some knowledge about synchronization points (or some intelligent pattern matching has to take place) as e.g. in the second file there could be new sections and old sections could be removed.

Comment: What OS should it run on? Any budget you'd be willing to spend if needed?

Comment: [Vivaldi Browser](https://vivaldi.com/) can open PDF files with Chromium builtin PDF reader, and can tile multiple tabs side by side for display

Comment: @Izzy macOS will be enough. To start with I was thinking to embed it on a Qt app, (not sure if QtWebEngine is the name of the thing) and use https://pdfobject.com perhaps.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Vivaldi seems to be the coolest peace of software I've seen last few days. But its not possible to scroll horizontally. Well, its a Browser, I'm looking for a PDF viewer.